# How to make LEFT JOIN to rows having max date in BQ?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables in Big Query:

TABLE A

| ID | Name | Date_A | field_x | field_y | field_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | tata | 10/11/2021 | a | 0 | 1 |
| xxx | tata | 11/11/2021 | a | 1 | 1 |
| zzz | tutu | 01/11/2021 | b | 0 | 1 |
| zzz | tutu | 05/11/2021 | b | 1 | 1 |
| yyy | titi | 02/11/2021 | c | 0 | 1 |
| uuu | tata | 08/11/2021 | d | 0 | 0 |

TABLE B

| ID | Name | Date_B | field_A | field_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | tata | 13/11/2021 | AA | BB |
| zzz | tutu | 01/11/2021 | CC | DD |
| yyy | titi | 11/11/2021 | AA | BB |
| uuu | tata | 05/11/2021 | DD | DD |

And I would like to link (left join on ID and Name) rows from table B to the max date of table A, to get :

| ID | Name | Date_A | field_x | field_y | field_z | field_A | field_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | tata | 10/11/2021 | a | 0 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| xxx | tata | 11/11/2021 | a | 1 | 1 | AA | BB |
| zzz | tutu | 01/11/2021 | b | 0 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| zzz | tutu | 05/11/2021 | b | 1 | 1 | CC | DD |
| yyy | titi | 02/11/2021 | c | 0 | 1 | AA | BB |
| uuu | tata | 08/11/2021 | d | 0 | 0 | DD | DD |

How can I do that in SQL (Big Query) please ? Thanks

Comment: If you're using Big Query (per your question's content) why tag spam 3 other RDBMS..? Don't tag spam, it doesn't help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select a.*, 
  (if(row_number() over win = 1, b, null)).* except(id, name, date_b)
from table_a a 
left join table_b b 
using(id, name)
window win as (partition by a.id, a.name order by date_a desc)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested it but I think you should left join the `b` table to `a` table in which the max date is indicated. Usage of condition pure on the left table is somewhat unusual though from the definition of left join I expect it to work.

```
select a_ranked.ID, a_ranked.Name, a_ranked.Date_A
     , a_ranked.field_x, a_ranked.field_y, a_ranked.field_z
     , b.field_A, b.field_B
from (
  select a.*, rank() over (partition by ID, Name order by Date_A desc) as r
  from a
) a_ranked
left join b on a_ranked.ID = b.ID and a_ranked.Name = b.Name and a_ranked.r = 1
```

Comment: This works but you need to correct the original select to be `a_ranked` rather than `a`

i.e. `a_ranked.ID, a_ranked.Name, a_ranked.Date_A, a_ranked.field_x, a_ranked.field_y, a_ranked.field_z`

Comment: @Cleanbeans aw, ugly typo, thanks, fixed